# Disposal not working

Tags: disposal

I have an Insinkerator 777ss disposal. It is hardwired.  When I flipped the switch it popped the breaker.  I removed the hot lead from the disposal, reset the breaker and flipped the switch.  Nothing happened and the breaker remained set.  I assume this means there is a short in the disposal?  I connected the hot lead and now when I flip the switch nothing happens and the breaker stays on. Is my next step replacing the disposal?  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: There is also a reset button on the bottom of the disposal.  Make sure the disposal can turn first also. There is also a hole in the center bottom of the disposal to insert a disposal wrench to help free a jammed disposal manually.

Comment: Do you have the user manual?

Answer (score 1):

Like tyson said, Reset the disposal on the bottom of the unit.  Then use an hex wrench in the hole in bottom center of the disposal to make sure the motor spins freely.  Let us know if that works.

Comment: I had the same symptoms, hitting reset and turning a few times with a hex key fixed it.